# Control linux console session keyboard over ssh

Tags: linux, keyboard, ssh

I have a logitech wireless keyboard/mouse, but just lost the tiny usb wireless receiver.

I want to use my laptop as the keyboard for the other machine (Ubuntu 10.10) until I replace the keyboard and mouse.

Is it possible to control the console session's keyboard over ssh? I only want keyboard control, I don't want to use something like VNC because the video is too slow.

EDIT: I'd like to be clear that I want to be able to control gui applications running on the console session, so something like gnu screen won't (as far as I know) help with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

x2x does exactly what you want:

```
$ ssh -X othermachine x2x -west -to :0
```

Now you can move your mouse to the left of your laptop and it wii appear in that other machine. Keyboard 'goes' there too.

You'll need to enable X forwarding in that other machine's sshd.

Comment: Read more about x2x here: http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/148824

Comment: Holy bajeebus. I now have a remote for my glorified netflix-player.

Comment: I can control the pointer on the remote machine (Raspberry Pi) but the keyboard stops working. I posted another question about it: http://superuser.com/questions/648291/no-keyboard-using-x2x-for-controlling-another-computer

Comment: Awesome. I can see some glitches though: Selecting some text isn't persistent. I can't cut and paste, for example. Is this something known?

Answer (score 1):

[Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) is a client/server application so you can share the keyboard+mouse on one (the server) with multiple other desktops (clients). I've used it for years and it's fairly easy to configure.

Comment: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier is the open source fork that is much more recent

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/).  These programs will start a console session that can be attached to from any ssh connection or local terminal.  Additionally, they let you open multiple console sessions inside the same parent screen/tmux session, allowing you to interact with multiple shells and console programs over a single connection.

Comment: OP may want to share a browser tab or other X based programs, which may not be possible with your suggestion.